# NGRX entity with store containing only a subset of records

Tags: database, api, ngrx, ngrx-entity

Recently made a component with state management using NGRX entity, where previously we have used straight up NGRX action->reducer->effect->selector.

From first impressions it seems to me that the design pattern expects you to load the total record set from your model into state, so thats what i did. Then I got thinking, what happens when this model starts to contain a lot of data.

So the question is, does entity make sense if you are only going to load a subset of data into state?

For example, if I load only a subset, then sorting a column in  table of that data doesn't work (as a user would expect) when implemented as an action on the store.

Comment: Maybe some actions should operate on the store and some should make api calls?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I got your question, but will try to answer anyway.

1. It does make sense to add ngrx entities to your reducer, when:

   - you are able to find unique identy for each entity in your state
   - end user actions will cause adding new entities to your state, updating or deleting existing entities

So if there is high probability that your entites will be inserted/updated/deleted - ngrx entities are the way to go.

2. It does not make sense to add ngrx entities to your reducer, when:

   - the entieties that you are storing won't be ever updated. This is overengineering really, plain array will do the trick here.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesnt answer the question

Comment: May you clarify what the question is about? Any code example would help. I thought the part that describes question is quite clear for me: `So the question is, does entity make sense if you are only going to load a subset of data into state?` - but apparently its not.